# can't initialize main class com.itranswarp.learnjava.Main

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-plugin

I've run an instance of MVC development of liaoxuefeng:      (https://www.liaoxuefeng.com/wiki/1252599548343744/1337408645759009)
Here is a link to download the package at the end of the web page
But when I run the Main Class, there is a mistake
`Error: can't initialize the main class: com.itranswarp.learnjava.Main Cause:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/catalina/WebResourceRoot`

```
Here is my pom.xml:
```

``

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.itranswarp.learnjava</groupId>
<artifactId>web-mvc</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>17</java.version>

    <jackson.version>2.12.7.1</jackson.version>
    <pebble.version>3.1.6</pebble.version>
    <tomcat.version>10.1.6</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.pebbletemplates</groupId>
        <artifactId>pebble</artifactId>
        <version>${pebble.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins
```

'''
I don't know why such error happens

```
I try to update my tomcat and plugins in pom.xml and download and use jdk17 to keep pace with the original maven, but I still can't save the problem
I just want to know how to solve the problem
```

Here is my Main Class
``
package com.itranswarp.learnjava;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(Integer.getInteger("port", 8080));
    tomcat.getConnector();
    Context ctx = tomcat.addWebapp("", new File("src/main/webapp").getAbsolutePath());
    WebResourceRoot resources = new StandardRoot(ctx);
    resources.addPreResources(new DirResourceSet(resources, "/WEB-INF/classes", new File("target/classes").getAbsolutePath(), "/"));
    ctx.setResources(resources);
    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
}
```

}
``

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

Comment: OK, I'm new here, aha

Comment: Could you edit and share the full error stack?

Comment: OK, the full error stack is 
Error: 
can't initialize the main class: com.itranswarp.learnjava.Main Cause:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/catalina/WebResourceRoot